# Centering text in row with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was starting to write a mock-up for a project. Basically, I use bootstrap grids to get a structure like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">Main Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f8fn9Los/4/

What I want to do is to center the Main title, not in its column but in the whole row. Is there any way to do this, while keeping this grid structure?

Ps: I know I can do this in other ways, but I was just wondering if there is some way to achieve this with grid.

Thanks!

Comment: Use text-center as classname

Comment: It will center the text in the col (see the fiddle), but I want to center it on the whole row (as if it was 2-8-2 for example)

Comment: Hmm the thing is that I dont understand why you put your main title inside of a col.

Comment: The grid elements are the containers of the stuff you want centered. You can't make the claim that the container is not centered and the text inside it is centered without some absolute positioning hack or setting the margin (which may cause grid elements to overlap). You can always set col-xs-3, col-xs-6, col-xs-3 and then center text align the middle div.

Comment: It's not the title of the website don't worry. This is a reporting pattern, and for each item I have to put one indicator, the title and then 3 others indicators, all on the same line. So I am just interesting in knowing if there some trick to center the title according to the row and not the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See you have already used `.text-center` on you `.project-name` which align text to `center`, so what I could suggest is that try `pseudo selector ::before` as below,

```
.text-center::before{
  content:"";
  margin-left:calc(100% - 75%);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

this would be what your looking for.

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 center-block text-center">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take another row only for `Main Tittle`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <h1 class="text-center">Project Name</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can put another row for other elements.

Comment: Yep, but the project name has to be in the middle of the indicators (it's a requirement) like in the fiddle. If I do this, the title will be upside the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the col-xs-offset-* class of bootstrap.

Have a look at this link for more details on this: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns