# How to center 2-columns in a Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center two columns in a row in Bootstrap and no matter what offset or centering, they won't stay on same line in center of full-width column on md size or above

Tried col-md-6 offset and adding row-center and column-center classes, nothing has worked

Here's the full footer code - I want the email and tel to be on one line on larger screens and the two social icons alongside each other on the next row. It wraps nicely to display on mobile, just the larger screens I need some help with.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="container-fluid footer-container">
    <div id="footer" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div id="action" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <btn class="footer-button">
                        <a href="contact.html" <h5 class="footer-items">BOOK NOW!</h5></a>
                    </btn>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contact-methods" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="send-email" href="mailto:bookings@samanthaharris.ca" target="-blank"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h5>Email Samantha</h5></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="call" href="tel:905-749-5700"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i><h5>905-749-5700</h5></a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-center"><a class="insta" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="-blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-center"><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="-blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: FYI you have a missing `>` in your code - the <a> element in your btn class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering text in row with bootstrap grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661118/centering-text-in-row-with-bootstrap-grid)

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment) try this way:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-*"></div>
 <div class="col-*"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'text-center' class to your rows.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="footer" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="action" class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <btn class="footer-button">
              <a href="contact.html" <h5 class="footer-items">BOOK NOW!</h5></a>
            </btn>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contact-methods" class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a class="send-email" href="mailto:bookings@samanthaharris.ca" target="-blank"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <h5>Email Samantha</h5>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a class="call" href="tel:905-749-5700"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <h5>905-749-5700</h5>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-center"><a class="insta" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="-blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-center"><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="-blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```